# Fully encrypted setup can't start after cold reset because of encrypted swap and main partition

Tags: boot, partitioning, encryption, swap

While researching my issue I found about the famous bug with the encrypted swap.
However my case seems to be different, because the problem persist after disabling the swap partition.
The problem moves to the main one and still can't start in anything but emergency mode.
Here are the details.

Ubuntu 16.10 with encrypted whole ssd, home dir and swap.
Today I did a hard reset by accident and it started in emergency mode after that.
If I select from the menu there to do fsck it gets to the swap partition and hangs there but If I ctrl+c it actually boots normally.
Once booted I disabled the swap partition (swapoff and commenting it out in /etc/fstab, it confirms as disabled in the monitor app)

however after restart it gives the same error (failing to access partition or something like that) but for the main partition.

Is there a way out of this without full resintall?

Comment: Check also in the `/etc/crypttab` comment it out there too, and try again..

Comment: Yes. I've did but forgot to mention. Swap is fully disabled, but it still doesn't start. Seems like disabling swap just transfers the problem to the main partition. Is reinstall the only option?

Comment: The other option is to reformat that `swap` partition to get rid of the `encryption format` using a `liveCD` of your OS